# Does small Laplacian imply small oscillation?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

Let us consider a compact Riemann manifold $(M,g)$ and a function $u$ on $(M,g)$. $u$ also satisfies that $|\triangle_g u|\leq \varepsilon$ where $\varepsilon$ is a small constant. Can we obtain that $\operatorname{\mathop{osc}}(u)\leq C_\varepsilon$ for some small constant $C_\varepsilon$ dependent only on $\varepsilon$ and the geometry of $(M,g)$?

If this is not true, how to construct a counterexample?

Comment: No, even if your manifold has dimension 1 (that is a circle).

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Thank you first! But in dimension 1, I think this is right. Since in dimension 1, the smallness of $\triangle_g u$ is equivalent to the smallness of the hessian $D^2 u$. Then by differential mean value theorem, we know $|Du(x)-Du(y)|\leq C_\varepsilon$ and if we take $y$ the maximal value point of $u$, we get the smallness of $Du$. And hence, we get the smallness of $osc (u)$ also by differential mean value theorem. Indeed, the question holds if we replace $\triangle u$ by $D^2 u$ for all dimension.

Comment: Up to addition by a constant, $u = -G \Delta u$, where $G$ is the Green operator for $-\Delta$. Known bounds for the kernel of $G$ imply that indeed the oscillation of $u$ is small.

Comment: Your constant $C_\epsilon$ depends not only on $\epsilon$ as you required but also on the manifold (on the length of the circle in case $n=1$. The mean value theorem involves the length of the interval!

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko I have edited the question such that $C_\varepsilon$ can dependent on the bounded geometry of $(M,g)$.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki Thank you so much for your answer! Because $M$ is a compact manifold, the kernel of $\triangle$ are just constant functions. So in this sense, the oscillation of $u$ should be small. Can you help to give a detailed proof?

Comment: @XiaoCao: Theorem 4.13 [here](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-1-4612-5734-9_4.pdf) gives all the necessary properties of the Green's function. If you need a more detailed answer, I should be more available next week, sorry.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki Ok! I will have a look. Thank you so much!